# Identify novel where someone repairs or restores an old house and gets involved in an environmental legal battle

Tags: identification-request

When the repairs to the house reached a certain level a native American conducted cleansing or blessing ceremony. The native American may have called the person "Carpenter" and one particular line of dialog was similar to "You do excellent work, Carpenter." There was a woman the "carpenter" met and that is where they got involved in a an environmental legal battle, perhaps with a mining company. I thought it might have been a book by Nicholas Sparks or Ron Rash, but I could not identify it from reviewing their works.

This was read on Radio Reader by Dick Estell not earlier than 2002. I can only find a list read by him up to 2005.